# Initialize dropdown in Angular Formgroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to set a default value to a drop-down control in a form using Angular FormGroup (I am using Angular 4). The drop-down populates well with the given list but the default value is not set.Also its not showing any error in the code Following is the code that I am using --

HTML Code

```
    <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label class="control-label" for="Country">Country</label>
    <select formControlName="CountryID" [(ngModel)]="CountryID" class="form-control">
        <option *ngFor="let country of Countries"  [ngValue]="country.CountryID">{{country.CountryName}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Typescript code

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.Countries = [
            { "CountryID": 0, "CountryName": "Select Country" },
            { "CountryID": 1, "CountryName": "Country 1" },
            { "CountryID": 2, "CountryName": "Country 2" },
            { "CountryID": 3, "CountryName": "Country 3" },
            { "CountryID": 4, "CountryName": "Country 4" },
            { "CountryID": 5, "CountryName": "Country 5" }
        ];

        this.inputProcessingForm = this._domBuilder.group({
            CandidateBuilderAppId: [''],
            FirstName: ['Amit'],
            MiddleInitial: '',
            LastName: '',
            Gender: 'S',
            DateOfBirth: new Date(),
            SocialSecurityNumber: 0,
            PersonalEmail: 'amanand@liventus.in',
            CorpEmail: '',
            HomePhone: '',
            WorkPhone: '',
            WorkCellPhone: '',
            WorkFax: '',
            WorkExtension: '',
            RemoteFax: '',
            Address1: '',
            Address2: '',
            CountryID: 0,
            State: 0,
            City: 0,
            ZipCode: 0
        });
}
```

Please suggest if I am doing anything wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try removing the `[(ngModel)]="CountryID"` from your template? Cause according to [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor), I'm guessing either one of the conventions (`formControlName` if using reactive forms or `ngModel` if using template driven forms) must be used, otherwise it might confuse the 'accessor'.